# What is the better way to do background tasks?

Tags: android, concurrency

I'm new to android dev, only been maybe 2 weeks in.
I'm learning with Udacity's courses. but their examples are a little outdated in this area.

In the course i'm on right now,
they are using AsyncTask and LoaderManager to run a background webquery to retrieve some data from USGS earthquake api.
but they are both apparently outdated.
I spent a long while and finally learned to use HandlerThread and Runnables to start a background task.
but in this lecture, they talked about memory leaks with using AsyncTask (when device rotate, activity gets created from scratch, but the task started still ran in the background)
so we will be learning to use LoaderManager with AsyncTask together.

now i'm wondering, what is the better approach to this now?

or does HandlerThread not have to worry about memory leak issue?

my code is below:

```
public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String URL_USGS = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=1&limit=50";

public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

private List<Earthquake> earthquakes;

private EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

    // Creating new background thread and retrieve its handler
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("BackGround");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

    // Run web query to retrieve date from USGS_URL
    backgroundHandler.post(() -> {
        earthquakes = QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes(URL_USGS);

        // get the UI Thread to update UI
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            earthquakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this, earthquakes);
            // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
            ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


            // attach onClick Listener to each item to link to USGS website
            earthquakeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String url = earthquakeAdapter.getItem(position).getUrl();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Set the adapter on the the ListView
            // so the list can be populated in the user interface
            earthquakeListView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapter);
        });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: honestly, my opinion, i don't think i've seen people using handler to schedule api calls anymore. newer and better ways of managing threads. rxjava, coroutines, even okhttp as a few different methods built in to manage this

Comment: thanks, i will look for some resource to learn them :)

Comment: give a try to work manager.

Comment: I would recommend against creating your own loaders. The main benefit is that they survive runtime configuration changes, but you can use [viewmodels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for that instead, which are much easier to use and more general.